# pthread_cond_signal doesn't unblock pthread_cond_wait thread immediately

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

I'm observing a behaviour which doesn't seem to be inline with how `pthread_cond_signal` and `pthread_cond_wait` should behave (accordingly to manpages).  `man 3 pthread_cond_signal` stipulates that:

> The pthread_cond_signal() function shall unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond (if any threads are blocked on cond).

This isn't precise enough and doesn't clarify if, at the same time, the thread calling `pthread_cond_signal` will yield its time back to the scheduler.

Here's an example program:

```
     1  #include <pthread.h>
     2  #include <iostream>
     3  #include <time.h>
     4  #include <unistd.h>
     5
     6  int mMsg = 0;
     7  pthread_mutex_t mMsgMutex;
     8  pthread_cond_t mMsgCond;
     9  pthread_t consumerThread;
    10  pthread_t producerThread;
    11
    12  void* producer(void* data) {
    13      (void) data;
    14      while(true) {
    15          pthread_mutex_lock(&mMsgMutex);
    16          std::cout << "1> locked" << std::endl;
    17          mMsg += 1;
    18          std::cout << "1> sending signal, mMsg = " << mMsg << "" << std::endl;
    19          pthread_cond_signal(&mMsgCond);
    20          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMsgMutex);
    21      }
    22
    23      return nullptr;
    24  }
    25
    26  void* consumer(void* data) {
    27      (void) data;
    28      pthread_mutex_lock(&mMsgMutex);
    29
    30      while(true) {
    31          while (mMsg == 0) {
    32              pthread_cond_wait(&mMsgCond, &mMsgMutex);
    33          }
    34          std::cout << "2> wake up, msg: " << mMsg << std::endl;
    35          mMsg = 0;
    36      }
    37
    38      return nullptr;
    39  }
    40
    41  int main()
    42  {
    43      pthread_mutex_init(&mMsgMutex, nullptr);
    44      pthread_cond_init(&mMsgCond, nullptr);
    45
    46      pthread_create(&consumerThread, nullptr, consumer, nullptr);
    47
    48      std::cout << "starting producer..." << std::endl;
    49
    50      sleep(1);
    51      pthread_create(&producerThread, nullptr, producer, nullptr);
    52
    53      pthread_join(consumerThread, nullptr);
    54      pthread_join(producerThread, nullptr);
    55      return 0;
    56  }
```

Here's the output:

```
starting producer...
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 1
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 2
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 3
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 4
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 5
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 6
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 7
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 8
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 9
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 10
2> wake up, msg: 10
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 1
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 2
1> locked
1> sending signal, mMsg = 3
...
```

It seems like there's no guarantee that any `pthread_cond_signal` will indeed immediately unblock any waiting `pthread_cond_wait` thread. At the same time it seems that any amount of `pthread_cond_signal` can be lost after first one has been issued.

Is this really the intended behaviour or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behavior. [pthread_cond_signal](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html) does not yield it's remaining runtime, but will continue to run.

And yes, `pthread_cond_signal` will immediately unblock (one or more) thread waiting on the corresponding condition variable. However, that doesn't guarantee that said waiting thread will immediately run. It just tells the OS that this thread is no longer blocked, and it's up to the OS thread scheduler to decide when to start running it. Since the signalling thread is already running, is hot in the cache etc., it will likely have plenty of time to do something before the now-unblocked thread starts doing anything.

In your example above, if you don't want to skip messages, maybe what you're looking for is something like a producer-consumer queue, maybe backed by a ring buffer.

Comment: Is there any reference to back that up? Can't find anything in the docs that would unequivocally state that.

Comment: @dagon: I added a link to the official specification. You have to read it a bit between the lines like a language lawyer. E.g. it doesn't say that `pthread_cond_signal` must yield, hence an implementation does not need to do that.

Comment: @dagon Even if it did, your thread that calls `pthread_cond_signal` still holds the mutex. So no thread that blocked on the condition variable could make forward progress before it did anyway.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: This is perfectly valid: man pthread_cond_signal: "The pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() functions may be called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that threads calling pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() have associated with the condition variable during their waits; however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal()."

Comment: @dagon I didn't say it wasn't valid, I just said it makes your question meaningless since the thread you want to make forward progress literally *can't* make forward progress no matter what the condition variable does since it needs a mutex that another thread holds. The thread holding the mutex *must* make forward progress first.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't think you read the sentence from the manpage that I've quoted.  It literally states that it's possible to call pthread_cond_signal with mutex locked and that this is even advised for more predictable scheduling

Comment: @dagon Yes, I read that. Did you read what I said? You are asking if one thread will make forward progress before another when that literally *cannot* happen since the thread you want to make forward progress first needs to acquire a mutex to make forward progress and the other thread holds that mutex.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you still don't get it... Nevermind, enjoy your day mate.